# Trigger to convert empty string to 'null' before it posts in SQL Server decimal column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, triggers

I've got a front table that essentially matches our `SSMS` database table `t_myTable`. Some columns I'm having problems with are those with numeric data types in the db. They are set to allow `null`, but from the front end when the user deletes the numeric value and tries to send a blank value, it's not posting to the database. I suspect because this value is sent back as an empty string `""` which does not translate to the `null` allowable data type.

Is there a trigger I can create to convert these empty strings into `null` on `insert` and `update` to the database? Or, perhaps a trigger would already happen too late in the process and I need to handle this on the `front end` or `API` portion instead?

We'll call my table `t_myTable` and the column `myNumericColumn`.

I could also be wrong and perhaps this 'empty string' issue is not the source of my problem. But I suspect that it is.

Comment: I don't believe a trigger will work because SQL Server will validate the date being inserted before calling the trigger. And really its not the place to validate data - your front end is. If you really had to do it this way you could create a view which allows a string instead of a number in that column, and the converts it and inserts to the table - but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: You won't get anywhere with a comment like "not posting to the database". That sounds like no row is inserted because an error occurred. Otherwise, how do you know "it does not post"?

Comment: And a trigger (after or instead-of) will not help. An empty string is implicitly converted to the numeric value 0 by the database engine. A trigger cannot "see" that the statement supplied an empty string - it only knows that zero is the value inserted (or to be inserted - depending on the type of trigger).

Answer (score 2):

As @DaleBurrell noted, the proper place to handle data validation is in the application layer. You can wrap each of the potentially problematic values in a [`NULLIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function, which will convert the value to a `NULL` if an empty string is passed to it.

The syntax would be along these lines:

```
SELECT
  ...
  ,NULLIF(ColumnName, '') AS ColumnName
```

Answer (score 0):

`select nullif(Column1, '') from tablename`

Comment: Please expand your answer explaining where your suggested SQL would run.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't allow to convert an empty string to the numeric data type. Hence the trigger is useless in this case, even INSTEAD OF one: SQL Server will check the conversion before inserting.

```
SELECT CAST('' AS numeric(18,2)) -- Error converting data type varchar to numeric
CREATE TABLE tab1 (col1 numeric(18,2) NULL);
INSERT INTO tab1 (col1) VALUES(''); -- Error converting data type varchar to numeric
```

As you didn't mention this error, the client should pass something other than `''`. The problem can be found with SQL Profiler: you need to run it and see what exact SQL statement is executing to insert data into the table.